# Timeline Chart framework, Flotr vs AmChart

Tags: javascript, charts, timeline, amcharts, flotr

I have been comparing many chart framework, and these two are the final contenders. There is no point to compare frameworks if there are no specifications. So, I will lay down my specifications and hope to have some responses, would be valuable to people having questions on which framework they should choose.

Final Goal : Stock Chart just like Google Finance
Points of interest
1. No Flash, for mobile device compatibility
2. No Charge (HighCharts is cool if you have money)
3. Annotation on Chart, for marking events
4. Zoom in/ Zoom out
5. Multiple Y-axes

Where do you think?

Answer (score 0):

All of the mentioned features are supported by amCharts:

1) it's SVG/VML based
2) free version is the same as commercial, only a small link to amcharts is displayed 
3) Here is example with events: http://amcharts.com/stock/events/
4) zoom-in, zoom-out is supported
5) multiple y axes are also supported: http://amcharts.com/javascript/line-chart-with-multiple-value-axes/